# Re-render/refresh application on runtime

Tags: marionette

I have the following question:
I have an application that I'm using Marionette.Layout and this Layout has regions.
I want to add the option to the user to change language(on run time), meaning after the application is already render and the user is working, he can change the language and all the application should be change it to the selected language.
My Question:
1. I need to 'refresh/re-render' all the application, how is this done, I didn't found or I miss it, how to re-render the application?

I already have a a mechanism that the 'templates' are like:
https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/issues/216 
This is working when the application is started, the first time, I need on run time to re-render/refresh with the new data

Comment: I have the exact same issue. My solution was to save the new language (and any session vars) into localStorage and the refresh the page. Not elegant I'll grant you

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there isn't anything in the Marionette to do this for you. You will have to write the code to re-render the entire application with the new language setting, yourself.

Comment: Does this mean you have never developed an application where you can change the language? I think is a pretty common scenario. If you have, would you mind sharing your strategy on that?